# Load an HTML page with a script and inspect it from the console

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

Is it possible to write a console script to load a html document(with javaScript) and after a while (for example 1 minute) take data from page that the script will generete ?

For example, when you run a console script that loads this page after minute output will be like this: 1234567....585960

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

</head>
<script>
var i = 0;
    setInterval(function() {
    i++;
    document.getElementById("out").innerHTML += i;
    }, 1000);
</script>
<body>
    <div id="out"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Look at this : https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer

Comment: Thank you very much, I did not find out how to use the selector to take values after some time, but the screenshots really work and the script really keeps the page open and it continues to work !!)